# Changes in sqlite file when creating new version of App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

i have a sqlite file in my app. the app is with enterprise certificate .

Now , if i am going to create new version with the changes in database then :

**1) i have to change my Sqlite file name ?**
**2) if yes , then is there any way that if any person who is using my app, who has his saved data in app , will be inserted automatically in new version of my app .**

otherwise if i create new file and then the older data would be removed!!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You might find this question and its answers useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554009/deploying-sqlite-db-on-iphone-app-upgrade

Comment: Best way is you should create structural changes in existing database only. It would be easy to do and more logical.

Comment: but if my app is in device and i am installing new version then how i can get new changes with take care that old data would remain there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) AFAIK, when you update, the old app bundle is replaced with the new app bundle. But the user data is untouched. i.e. the copy of the sqlite DB which the app changes with use by the user, is not deleted/replaced.

2) So, you can possibly ship changes to the DB as queries:

a) New tables go in as `CREATE TABLE` queries.

b) Changes to table structure go in as `ALTER TABLE` queries.

3) Now, one problem is, you didn't think about all this when you shipped the older version. So how will you make sure the queries **2a** and **2b** are executed only on upgrade?

a) When you first get control in the application, before allowing user interaction, fire a dummy `SELECT SINGLE * FROM <tablename>` on a table you have 'changed' in new version.

b) Use `sqlite3_column_count` and `sqlite3_column_name` to find out which version of the app the DB corresponds to [old or new].

c) If it is new version (i.e. new columns already exist), do nothing, else fire the queries I mentioned earlier as **2a** and **2b**.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't started by using this, then it's probably moot, but Core Data handles migrations (IMHO) fairly well; enough that it's worth the hurdle of learning the API. We've had great success with it (including complex migrations, inserting new objects "between" relationships, etc).